# How create mount point in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose

I want create mount point for file path `/my/host/dir`. I create volumes in `docker-compose.yml`

```
volumes:
  data-db: /my/host/dir
```

and i try use `db-data`

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

but i get `ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume 'db-data' must be a mapping not a string.`

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db-data: /home/db/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Notice the deleted path under the root volumes key. The root "volumes" only specifies that it exists, not the path where. For more info and list of available configuration options check [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference).

To elaborate more what the error means... You can specify the volume like this:

```
volumes:
  db-data:
    external: true
    name: my-db-data
```

So docker expects the "thing" following the `:` after `db-data` to be a key/value mapping. But you provided string `/home/db` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up to [Tomáš Fejfar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459948/4575793): you can also define the volumes in a `docker-compose.yml` like this. In my opinion, this makes keys and values more readable. The mapping is important:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: db-data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db-data:
    external: true
    name: my-db-data
```

This resembles the commands

- `docker run [...] -v db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data <name>` or
- `docker run [...] --mount type=bind,source=db-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data <name>`

respectively.

As [already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459948/4575793), you should consider [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference).